# Toggle display with switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been racking my brain around this for a while now and can't seem to find any answers that work for me. I'm trying to have a button that toggles the `display` property from `none`, to `block`. Using pure JavaScript.

The code will hide it when I click but won't set the display property back to what it needs to be. Is there a problem with selecting an element once it's hidden?

```js
let m = 1;

function show() {
  document.getElementById('cardContainer').style.backgroundColor = "block"
  m = 1;
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById('cardContainer').style.display = 'none'
  m = 0;
}

function toggle() {
  if (m === 0) {
    show();
  } else {
    hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#cardContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#cardM1,
#cardM2,
#cardM3 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle();">Click</button>

<div id="cardContainer">
  <div id="cardM1">
    <!--Stuff added later here-->
  </div>

  <div id="cardM2">
    <!--Stuff added later here-->
  </div>

  <div id="cardM3">
    <!--Stuff added later here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I'm trying to avoid using JQuery for the time being. Can this be done with vanilla JS?

Comment: Read out loud: `backgroundColor = "block"` - sounds suspicious?

Comment: BTW, all you need is one line inside the click handler: `document.getElementById('cardContainer').classList.toggle("is-hidden")` and one CSS rule: `.is-hidden { display: none; }`. What you have is an overcomplication for something that trivial.

Comment: `"block"`is a wrong `backgroundColor` in `style.backgroundColor = "block"`...

Comment: Just change ```document.getElementById('cardContainer').style.backgroundColor = "block"``` to ```document.getElementById('cardContainer').style.display = "block"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do that 'Using pure JavaScript'...

```js
const cardContainer = document.querySelector('#cardContainer')
  ; 
function toggle()
  {
  cardContainer.classList.toggle('noDisplay');
  }
```

```css
#cardContainer {
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 50%;
  left             : 50%;
  transform        : translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding          : 10px;
  border-radius    : 15px;
  background-color : #000000;
  }
#cardM1,
#cardM2,
#cardM3 {
  background-color : #ffffff;
  display          : inline-block;
  padding          : 25px;
  margin           : 10px;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle();">Click</button>

<div id="cardContainer">
  <div id="cardM1">
    <!--Stuff added later here-->
  </div>

  <div id="cardM2">
    <!--Stuff added later here-->
  </div>

  <div id="cardM3">
    <!--Stuff added later here-->
  </div>
</div>
```